# How can I show loading spinner when initializing a ES6 class in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, react-hooks

I have a React(Hook) button with a onClick function, here is my React Hook component:

```
function FormatButton(props) {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  function handleClick(){
    const formatter = new Formatter(props.filterResult);
  }
  
   return (
     <Styles>
       {(props.filterResult.length > 0 ? 
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Convert</button>
           : '')}
       <RingLoader
          size={150}
          color={"#35D4C7"}
          loading={loading}
        />
     </Styles>
   )
 }

export default FormatButton;
```

here is my Formatter class (Not a react component):

```
class Formatter{
    constructor(data=[]){
        this.data = _.map(data, currData => {
                return _.mapValues(currData,value=>{ return this.format(value)})
            })
    }
}
```

I am using `react-spainners` which I only need to pass a boolean type state value `loading` for the spinner, I would like to set `loading` as `ture` when `const formatter = new Formatter(props.filterResult);` start running, and then set `loading` as `false` when the Formatter class initialization is done. 
I am thinking maybe I can use async/await but not really know how to use it in class initializing, are there any other ways to achieve it? Thanks a lot for helping!!

Comment: This doesn't look like an asynchronous action, why do you need a spinner?

Comment: @goto1 I would like to show a loading screen when initializing a class, then hide it when it done

Comment: Initializing a class is not an asynchronous action, you don't need a spinner to create a new instance of a class. Unless there's more to the Formatter class that you're note showing, I don't see a need for a spinner here...